# Can I manipulate HTML with javascript in the head in order to make a page 508 compliant?

Tags: javascript, section508

I am looking at using a 3rd party application for part of the BI tool that must be 508 compliant and do not have direct access to the 3rd party tool.  I do, however, have access to the head and I can put javascript in the head.  Can this be done to make the 3rd party tool 508 compliant?  Are there any gotcha's to manipulating HTML into being 508 compliant with javascript in the head?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4270323/14357) seems relevant.

Comment: @spender thanks... I did just read that before posting the answer.  So to clarify, I can do anything I want in javascript as long as what is rendered is accessible?  I've also read that the <noscript> tag is not required: http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=4795